# What repositories do I need to install heartbeat and haproxy on RHEL?

Tags: rhel, yum

So I am now managing two RHEL machines that I need to install `haproxy` and `heartbeat` on. When I follow instructions to do so I get the following:

```
[admin@p2378442 ~]$ sudo yum -y install heartbeat haproxy
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * main-base: yum01tor.peer1.com
 * main-extras: yum01tor.peer1.com
 * main-updates: yum01tor.peer1.com
Setting up Install Process
No package heartbeat available.
No package haproxy available.
Nothing to do
[admin@p2378442 ~]$
```

Comment: and this is why I don't like "repository distro's" sure arch has repo's but you don't have to go looking for them to get stuff done. Trust me, for someone who doesn't use repository distro's *ubuntu* is just as frustrating to me.

Comment: As an FYI, heartbeat is discontinued and is no longer maintained (last release was in 2011). It's deprecated in favor of corosync & pacemaker.

Answer (score 3):

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL had them both.

You can add it like so:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: IIRC, redhat 6 has an official "HA repo" which contains packages like this.